# Speed up Automator workflow

Tags: automator, automation

I've recorded some actions and made an Automator workflow out of it. It's basically some clicks, selecting something in drop-down menues and quitting the app. I run the workflow at 10x speed, but it's still fairly slow. Is there a way to speed it up beyond 10x? It can also run in the background, invisibly, I don't need to see the steps. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Are you hoping to save seconds or minutes per run? Which actions consume the bulk of the time – is it the application being automated? Are you able to share more information about the applications involved and the workflow?

Comment: I was trying to make smaller sized PDFs from larger ones (I mean the file size). Acrobat was producing bad quality, but Preview using Quartz filter worked just fine. I wanted to use Keyboard Maestro, but couldn't get to the dropdown menu. So my recorded workflow was 1. open file in Preview 2. Click the File tab 3. Hold Alt key 4. Click Save As (which is not available without Alt key) 5. In the drop-down select the Quartz filter Reduce file size 6. Save 7. Confirm overwriting original file 8. Cmd-W
All the mouse movements are sort of slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this alternative approach in Automator. Be sure to back up any PDFs before applying this workflow – the originals will be overwritten.

In Automator.app, create a new workflow and add the following actions:

1. **Ask for Finder Items**, with **Allow Multiple Selection**
2. **Apply Quartz Filter to PDF Documents**, selecting the **Reduce File Size** option
   [image: Compress PDF workflow]

When run this workflow will let you select multiple PDFs and then overwrite those files with reduced file size versions. It performs the equivalent steps as the original workflow, but is faster than scripting Preview.app.

Comment: Sorry, it's a new account because of password problems and I can't seem to comment. I've already tried the workflow you describe, but the problem was that it didn't respect the cropping applied in Acrobat, the Preview method did. In the Quartz filter options I couldn't find anything regarding cropping :(

Comment: Unfortunate the Automator action does not offer the same options. Try [asking a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) saying what you want to achieve with your PDFs – reduce their file size and crop them. A new question focused on your intention should open up your options. I suspect command line tools and other approaches will be suggested.

Comment: @linda20162 Please use the [contact form](http://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) to have your accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the steps from inside the watch-me-do into the main workflow.  This will turn each step into a little Applescript that you can edit.  It uses a different means of clicking menu items that don't involve actually moving the cursor.  There's also a delay in the code that you can edit.  Note however that since it's a different means of clicking menu items, you may need to test it to make sure everything still works as intended.  I've had to increase delays to overcome things like waiting for an app to "activate".  And some watch-me-do actions may not be able to be dragged into the workflow and turned into Applescripts.